# How does a converting constructor with more than a single non-optional parameter look like and why does it make sense?

Tags: c++, constructor, c++11, type-conversion, language-lawyer

As far as I have used "converting constructors" they look like this:

```
struct X {
  X(A); // conversion from A -> X
  X(B,C = someC); // conversion from B -> X, with some default C
};
X x1 = A(); // calls X::X(A())
X x2 = B(); // calls X::X(B(),someC)
```

This makes perfect sense, and as far as I know works as long as you don't have a constructor:

```
struct Y {
  Y(A,B); // no implicit conversion
};
```

However, this is where it gets interesting, the C++11 standard reads literally:

> **12.3.1 Conversion by constructor**
>
> 1. A constructor declared without the function-specifier `explicit` <s>that can be called with a single parameter</s> specifies a
>      conversion from the <s>type of its first parameter</s> *types of its parameters* to the type of its class. Such a constructor is called
>      a converting constructor.

(italics were originally underlined, but markdown doesn't accept `<u>`)

This seems to suggest that it was *changed* that a converting constructor doesn't have to be callable "with a single parameter" and the change from "type of its first parameter" to "type**s** of its parameters" (note the plural!) further supports this. While I would expect that "type of its first parameter" would be changed to "type of its single non-optional parameter" (1) or even "type of its parameter that received an explicit argument" (2) in order to allow these:

```
struct Z {
  Z(A = a, B, C = c); // (1)
  Z(D = d, E = e, F = f); // (2)
};
Z = D(); // (2)
Z = E(); // (2)
```

I don't see how the formulation with the plural form makes sense: **Does it really indicate you can perform conversion with several arguments? What does this mean?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The language was modified as part of the addition of initializer lists.  See [n2672:  init-list wording](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2672.htm).

An example:

```
struct S {
    S(int x, double y) { }
};

void f(S) { }

int main() {
    f({ 42, 42.0 });
}
```

Comment: As a tip:  when you find wording that is different between C++98/03 and C++11, it's often helpful to search for a small piece of the new text on Google (or, uh, Bing...).  For example, here, a search for "types of its parameters to the type of its class" has a link to n2672 as its third result (well, fourth now, since this question is now ranked #1).